# How to compare\assert double values in rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm trying to compare\assert double from a JSON with java primitive double value. 
What is the proper way to do it?

I used simple and regular way to do it, using `Matchers.equalTo` method, see below

```
public class A{
       private static double someJavaDouble = 12
}
```

```
given().
        header(.....).
when().
        get(url).
then().
        statusCode(200)
        body("value", Matchers.equalTo(someJavaDouble))
```

Response of `get(url)` is JSON:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "currentValue": 12.0
}
```

In the code above I get this error:

```
JSON path currentValue doesn't match.
Expected: <12.0>
  Actual: 12.0
```

p.s.
it works if

```
body("value", Matchers.equalTo(12f))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion over REST Assured floating-point comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815071/confusion-over-rest-assured-floating-point-comparisons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value returned by `JSON Serializer` is `Double`, not the primitive data type `double`.
You can get double value from Double `Double.doubleValue()` or convert double to Double `new Double(someJavaDouble)`

```
body("value", Matchers.equalTo(new Double(someJavaDouble)))
```

Answer (score 4):

RestAssured parses numbers as `Float` by default.

Based on [github issue 1315](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/1315) You can configure it to parse it to Double:

```java
JsonConfig jsonConfig = JsonConfig.jsonConfig()
    .numberReturnType(JsonPathConfig.NumberReturnType.DOUBLE);

RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config()
    .jsonConfig(jsonConfig);
```

Comment: If you are wondering where you need to put this, you can put this inside @BeforeAll of your Test class.