# Expected and actual matching but test is failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, rest-assured

Using rest-assured to invoke a base rest service with:

```
  given().get(baseUrl + "/base/")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("size()", is(2))
                .body("meanPerDay", equalTo(1.5))
```

returns :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path meanPerDay doesn't match.
Expected: <1.5>
  Actual: 1.5
```

The payload of `baseUrl + "/base/"` is:

```
{
    "meanPerDay": 1.5,
    "stdPerDay": 0.5
}
```

If I replace .body("meanPerDay", equalTo(1.5)) with .body("meanPerDay", equalTo("1.5"))

the failure is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path meanPerDay doesn't match.
Expected: 1.5
  Actual: 1.5
```

I'm not accessing the `meanPerDay` attribute correctly?

The test is finding the attribute value as the `Expected` is value 1.5?

Comment: I think that the type of the expected value is not the same of the type of  actual value.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56114915/how-to-compare-assert-double-values-in-rest-assured

Comment: @StefanoCurcio Using .body("meanPerDay",  Matchers.equalTo(Double.valueOf(1.5))); causes error: java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path meanPerDay doesn't match.
Expected: <1.5>
  Actual: 1.5 , answer provided by Peter Quan seems to work but I'm not sure why using Matchers is causing a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below numbers are floating point

```
{
    "meanPerDay": 1.5,
    "stdPerDay": 0.5
}
```

, however, the following test is comparing with a "double":

```
 .body("meanPerDay", equalTo(1.5))
```

So, you can try this:

```
 .body("meanPerDay", equalTo(1.5f))
```